# How do I get rid of double quotes in a Matlab cell?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have an array of cells in Matlab that all elements in the cell are expressed as:

```
'"something"'
```

How can I create an array of

```
'something'
```

?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I just noticed that you've asked several questions, but haven't marked any of them answered. If you feel someone has satisfactorily answered your question, you should click the tick mark next to their answer. If you do this, people will be more inclined to help you in the future. You can go back and do this for all the questions you've asked thus far using [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1781548/user1781548). Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two solutions. `strrep` removes all instances of double quotes, while `regexprep` only removes double quotes at the start and end of the string (thanks to Gunther Struyf for pointing out that the second `regexprep` solution would be needed in some scenarios):

```
>> A = {'"hello"', '"wor"ld"'}

A = 

'"hello"'    '"wor"ld"'

>> B = strrep(A, '"', '')

B = 

'hello'    'world'

>> C = regexprep(A, '^"|"$', '')

C = 

'hello'    'wor"ld'
```

Comment: assuming there are no other `'` in the strings. In that (unlikely) case, [regexprep](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) will do the trick

Comment: @GuntherStruyf Good point, although I assume you meant no other `"`, not `'`. I'll adjust my answer when I get home from work. Cheers.

Comment: ah, yes indeed, just added it for future reference as an alternative to `strrep`

Answer (score 0):

This does not work for numbers

regexprep(string(67), '^"|"$', '')

ans =

```
"67"
```